# Reorganize number order

Tags: notepad++

I have a form like this:

seven digits - three numbers - two - two numbers

live example:

```
7777777 - 123 - 12 - 12
```

I want to reorganize the form and put every three I have in the list in the last of the line

to become like this

```
7777777 - 12 - 12 - 123
```

“-” is just for separation purpose my form has no “-” included just spaces

is this possible by using notepad++?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all your lines are the same format, you can do replace with regex:

Find what:

```
(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)
```

Replace with:

```
$1$4$5$6$7$2$3
```

Make sure to have "Regular expression" checked

This will in every line which consists of 4 blocks of numbers (the count of numbers in each block does not matter) move the second block of numbers to be the last one.  `\d+` searches of a block of numbers (at least 1), `\s+` searches for a block of whitespaces (at least 1). `(\d+)` is a capturing group, such that you can access the found block in the replacement by its number `$1` ... `$7`. So `$1` is the first block of digits, `$2` is the first block of whitespaces, `$3` is the second block of digits, `$4` is the second block of whitespaces, and so on. By reordering the blocks, it moves the second block of digits to be the last one.